# Do not highlight table view row when touched

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, highlight

When I select a row of a table view, it becomes blue. I want the row to not change color when I touch it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

each cell will need one of these:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disallow selection of *all* rows in your table, then in the setup of your table's view controller (such as in `viewDidLoad`), set

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Under the cellforrowatindexpath, assign a variable to the 'cell' object

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```